# android and 3rd party jars

Tags: java, android

I have a jar file I use it to use TOC protocol (AOL servers).That jar file works fine totaly fine with my java application but when I use it in my android app,it never runs.I don't know the problem at all and I ma newbie to android development.plz help and guide me on how to debug android app or get console prints from android app IF YOU PLEASE.
Best regards

Comment: take a look at the log -> logcat (Android doesn't use System.out for logging)

Comment: You need to give us more information, like the code you have written and details of the errors/exceptions you get.  What do you mean by "it never runs"?

Comment: What I mean by it never runs is when my emulator starts and the apk installed in it by eclipse,I get always an error message in the emulator.the jar file uses just printstreams and sockets.My android app works well without any call to any method in that 3rd party jar,but when I just creat new object from any class in that jar,I got this error (The application NDROID (process ......) has stoped unexpectedly. Please try again ).That jar works well with my java application but with android ,nooo,what I miss to make it work in my android app.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Android prints to its "console" using the Log utility. You can read about how it works at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html.

Basically you use a line like Log.e("AppName", "Message to print"), then go the the Debug view in eclipse and look at the window called LogCat. If you are running on an actual device instead of an emulator you can view this log through ADB. I also sometimes use a free app from the market called aLogCat to quickly check the log on the device its self.